# How to pass the value from the function incoming while working with socket in React native

Tags: react-native

I'm working with socket in react native for that I have installed 2 libraries `isomorphic-ws` and `ws`

```
 ws.onmessage = function incoming(data) {
          responseData = data.data
        };
```

I get the response perfect and stored in `responseData`, but I can't be able to take that response to any method just like below.

```
ws.onmessage = function incoming(data) {
      this.getResponse(data.data);
    };
```

I have tried the following ways :
1.

```
ws.onmessage = function incoming(data) {
      this.getResponse(data.data);
    };
```

2. Take a var out of the class and store the data.data in that variable and print that in the render

   ws.onmessage = function incoming(data) {
         this.getResponse(data.data);
       };

I want to take a response data to a function.